# Unable to start the sandbox on Azure sandbox

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cloud

I am trying to activate sandboxes. When I enter my mobile no which is in sync with my live account which has a domain like @outlook.com which I am not receiving the code to my phone.

Even tried in incognito but no luck.

Initially when i tried a few months back no phone no is asked which directly worked with my no.

Now it is asking for phone code to authorize.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing the "[MSA account requires additional verification steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/support/troubleshooting)" message, the Microsoft account that you use to sign into Microsoft Docs may need verification if you haven't used that account for a while, or if your account requires email or phone verification. You will need to resolve your account login issue through https://support.microsoft.com to use it on Microsoft Docs.

MVA Learning also has an active [support forum here](https://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/tcml/forum/tcml_mat-tcml_nocourse-tcml_other).

[Other things to note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/troubleshoot-azure-sign-up):

- You can use any phone number for verification as long as it meets the requirements. The phone number that you enter for verification isn't stored as a contact number for the account.
- A Voice-over-IP (VoiP) phone number can't be used for the phone verification process.
- Check that your phone can receive calls or SMS messages from a United States-based telephone number.
- Double-check the phone number that you enter, including the country code that you select in the drop-down menu.
- If your phone doesn't receive text messages (SMS), try the Call me option.

The [MS learn help page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/support/) may also be useful, but I would suggest reaching out to support.